# Unfortunately app has stopped. What does java.lang.NullPointerException mean?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I press run an my app I get this message. CAnanyone help me please? I am posting my LogCat here:

```
09-10 21:40:54.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11894): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-10 21:40:54.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11894): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shoppingapp/com.example.shoppingapp.CurrencyConverter}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-10 21:40:54.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11894):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
09-10 21:40:54.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11894):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
09-10 21:40:54.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11894):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
09-10 21:40:54.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11894):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
09-10 21:40:54.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11894):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-10 21:40:54.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11894):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-10 21:40:54.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11894):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
09-10 21:40:54.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11894):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-10 21:40:54.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11894):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-10 21:40:54.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11894):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
09-10 21:40:54.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11894):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
09-10 21:40:54.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11894):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-10 21:40:54.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11894): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-10 21:40:54.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11894):    at com.example.shoppingapp.CurrencyConverter.onCreate(CurrencyConverter.java:36)
09-10 21:40:54.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11894):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5184)
09-10 21:40:54.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11894):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
09-10 21:40:54.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11894):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
09-10 21:40:54.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11894):    ... 11 more
```

I am posting The CurrencyConverter class here.  I have seen line 36. Maybe the error is there because I dont find simple_spinner_item in R.java...What can I do?

```
package com.example.shoppingapp;

import com.example.shoppingapp.ConvertECB;
import com.example.shoppingapp.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CurrencyConverter extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.start_app);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
        final Button count = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final EditText curr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entry);
        final TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.converted);
        final TextView date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        // stworzenie parsera

        final ConvertECB cp = new ConvertECB (this);

        date.setText("Last updated: " + cp.getPubDate()
                + ". Data received from ECB.");
        // tablica z symbolami walut
        final String spinner_array[] = new String[cp.currencyCode.size()];

        // przypisanie pobranych symboli do tablicy
        for (int i = 0; i < cp.currencyCode.size(); i++) {
            spinner_array[i] = cp.currencyCode.get(i);
        }

        // ustawienie tablicy z symbolami walut jako listy dla spinnerow oraz
        // wygladu
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinner_array);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);

        // okienko pytajace przy probie wyjscia z programu
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                finish();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        // listnery do przyciskow
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final AlertDialog alert;
                alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        });
        count.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {

                    float value = Float.parseFloat(curr.getText().toString());
                    value = value
                            * cp.getRelativeExchange(spinner.getSelectedItem()
                                    .toString(), spinner1.getSelectedItem()
                                    .toString());
                    result.setText(String.valueOf(value));
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    result.setText(R.string.error);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: A `NullPointerException` can occur when you try to dereference a `null` reference. Is some reference in your program `null`?

Comment: This link explains all the causes of a null pointer exception http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html

Comment: The stack trace tells you "21:40:54.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11894): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 09-10 21:40:54.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11894): at com.example.shoppingapp.CurrencyConverter.onCreate(CurrencyConverter.java:36) 09-10 " meaning something that hasn't been created is initalizing in the onCreate() method of CurrencyConverter object.

Comment: Take a look at the "Caused by" section. The fatal issue is occurring in your `CurrencyConverter` class, at line 36. What's happening there in your code?

Comment: What's on line 36 of the CurrencyConverter class?

Comment: It looks like either `date` or `cp` is `null`. Put a breakpoint on line 36 and see which one. If its `date` then you don't have the correct `id` of the `TextView` in your `start_app.xml`

Answer (score 3):

> What does java.lang.NullPointerException mean?

This means that you are trying to use a variable, probably by setting a method on it or a listener. Here is how we read it.

> 09-10 21:40:54.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11894): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

this tells us that the app stopped working. The first line that tells us what it is caused by

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

tells us a `NPE`. Then the next line after that which references your project is a good place to start.

> at com.example.shoppingapp.CurrencyConverter.onCreate(CurrencyConverter.java:36)

line 36 `CurrencyConverter`. Something is `null` there....try to figure out what and why. If you need more help please post relevant code.

Comment: I am publishing the CurrencyConverter Class

Comment: Please don't post the whole class...just the `onCreate()`

Comment: Sorry for posting the whole class. I saw your comment now

Comment: Ok, see my comment above and figure out which is `null` if I counted lines right. If not then tell us which line is 36

Comment: Lne 36 and 37 are:                                                                            date.setText("Last updated: " + cp.getPubDate()
    + ". Data received from ECB.");

Comment: Yes, so one of those two are `null`. Read my comment above, under your post. If it isn't `date` then it is `cp`

Comment: but what can I do if cp is null? Sorry for my question but I am  new in programing

Comment: I don't know anything about that class. You will need to look at that class and see how the constructor would return `null`